# Как подключить android к сайту?

Tags: android

Имеется сайт с обновляемой информацией. Есть приложение, что-то типа браузера для всего одного сайта. Хотелось бы сделать нативное приложение, только не пойму как его связать с сайтом, чтобы в Андроиде обновлялась информация которая добавляется на сайте? Сайт на php + mysql. 
Как это делается? На каких программах, фреймах и тп. Как проще?

Comment: Можно рассмотреть возможность сконвертировать сайт под PWA. Подробности:
https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B1-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Серверу передаются запросы (GET/POST), сервер возвращает JSON-массив данных, которые обрабатываются и отображаются в приложении. Проще всего (на мой субъективный взгляд) для создания подобного приложения использовать React Native.
Основную информацию я дал, подробнее расписывать займёт стену текста, да и к тому же все эти процессы давно уже расписали, достаточно загуглить то что я выше написал. Удачи!